# Excel 2010: Get next months 1st Tuesday from a date generated with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program:**  Excel 2010
**Experience Level:** Basic

Hi there,
I am creating an Invoice which pulls data in from other sheets via VLOOKUP, the page is full of formulas and code (which I'm happy with), however I am having an issue when it comes to setting a date.

**The issue:**
When I use the formula to get my "1st Tues of the following Month" referencing cell `(F3)` the formula does not work.  The date in `(F3)` has been generated by a VLOOKUP, so I believe my new formula is erroring out because it doesn't have a "Date", just a result of code.

Here are my formulas:

```
Cell(F3)    =IF(TEXT(VLOOKUP($F$2,OrdSum,24,FALSE),"mmm-dd-yyyy")="","",(TEXT(VLOOKUP($F$2,OrdSum,24,FALSE),"mmm-dd-yyyy")))
```

**Results:**  Jan-31-2014  (It is pulling the last day of the sales month which I manually write in every month from my OrdSum, I don't want it dynamic).

```
Cell(A14)    =((EOMONTH(F3,0)+1)+7)+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY((EOMONTH(F3,0)+1)),2,1,0,6,5,4,3)
```

**Results**: #VALUE!

However if I have a hardcoded date in any cell the formula works and returns `11/02/2014`
.

Even a simple `=EOMONTH(F3,1)` does not work, it results in the `#VALUE!` error.

Is there a workaround? Or do I have to write in the EOM manually on the Invoice as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Jerry answered your question - I note that A14 is giving you **2nd** Tuesday of the next month - you can do that more easily with this formula: `=EOMONTH(F3,0)+15-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(F3,0)+5)`

Comment: Thank you @barryhoudini can you please tell me which is the Number that changes the Day/Freq.  (so: 3rd Friday,  4th Wednesday etc).  I would have accepted yours as the answer, thank you.

Comment: @MrsAdmin The variable is the last `5` there. Well, it's more like 7-5 really, giving 2 for Tuesday. If you want 2nd Wednesday, you need to use 4, which would mean 7-4 = 3 for Wednesday. It's kind of 'reversed'.

Comment: Thank you @Jerry I have both answers in my book now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `VLOOKUP` is already pulling a date, you don't really need the `TEXT` part (you don't need it since if the `VLOOKUP` returns a blank, `TEXT` will convert it to `00-01-1900` anyway), this should suffice:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($F$2,OrdSum,24,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP($F$2,OrdSum,24,FALSE))
```

For cell F3. You only need to format F3 as `mmm-dd-yyyy` through custom formatting or date formatting.

EDIT: @Barryhoudini had a simpler formula for the 2nd Tuesday of the month. credit goes to him for this, I'm just elaborating a bit more here:

```
=EOMONTH(F3,0)+15-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(F3,0)+5)
```

Will give the date of the 2nd Tuesday of the month. The last `5` is what determines what day of the week it is. You could perhaps re-write it like this to make it simpler:

```
=EOMONTH(F3,0)+15-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(F3,0)+(7-3))
```

Where `3` is Wednesday. You can change the last number to mean these:

```
0 or 7 Sunday
1      Monday
2      Tuesday
3      Wednesday
4      Thursday
5      Friday
6      Saturday
```

Comment: that was a copy & paste/edit from the previous cell where I had  `CONCAT` Date & RefID to make the report number :)  Thank you, I've cleaned it up.

Comment: @MrsAdmin Added the formula of barryhoudini and some explanation to my answer (credit goes to him for the formula).

Answer (score 1):

The following formula, at the expense of some verbosity, does away with the VLOOKUP (which always makes spreadsheets brittle), and any formatting considerations.

If cell A1 contains a date, then

```
=1 + EOMONTH(A1,0) + MOD(3 - WEEKDAY(1 + EOMONTH(A1,0)),7)
```

returns a date that is the first Tuesday of the following month. Tuesday has a weekday value of `3` which is why this literal appears as the first term in the `MOD(`.

If you wanted to centre on, say Thursday (which has a weekday value of `5`), then write

```
=1 + EOMONTH(A1,0) + MOD(5 - WEEKDAY(1 + EOMONTH(A1,0)),7)
```

Comment: Thank you @Bathsheba.  can you please tell me which is the Number that changes the Day/Freq. (so: 3rd Friday, 4th Wednesday etc).   My sheet is full of the VLOOKUPS until I can afford to get the book converted to VBA :D

Comment: @MrsAdmin: I've added this to the answer and try to avoid VBA unless absolutely necessary. (Mainly as it's such a maintenance headache).

Comment: thank you for your help.  I have added the Formula to my sheet & added the shortlink to my reference page so I don't lose it :)  I have some decisions to make about how I want the book to finish with, I am muddling through YouTube, "How-tos" and best "Invoice Practices". It's a mess :D